# Is the kernel of a morphism of finite group schemes finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

is the kernel of homorphism of finite group schemes once again finite?

(i.e. if you have $G = Spec A, H = Spec B$ over a field $k$, i.e. $A,B$ finite dimensional $k$-vector spaces, is ker$\varphi$ once again finite?)

In my opinion, this should be equivalent to asking whether the $k$-algebra given by $A/I_BA$, where $I_B$ is the augmentation ideal of $B$, is finite dimensional as a $k$-vector space. Is this true? I don't seem to get anywhere with this :)

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "Is the kernel of homorphism of finite group schemes once again finite?"

**Answer:** Let $\phi: H:=Spec(k[H]) \rightarrow G:=Spec(k[G])$ be a map of affine group schemes of finite type over a field $k$. It follows the kernel $K:=ker(\phi)$
is a closed subgroup scheme of $H$. Hence if $H$ is a finite group scheme it follows $K$ is a finite group scheme.

**Proof:** Let $f: k[G] \rightarrow k[H]$ be the canonical map.
Let $\mathfrak{m}_e \subseteq k[G]$ be the maximal ideal of the identity element $e \in G$. It follows there is an equality of sets

$$\{\mathfrak{m} \subseteq k[H]: f^{-1}(\mathfrak{m})=\mathfrak{m}_e\}=V(f(\mathfrak{m}_e)) \subseteq H.$$

Hence the kernel $K:=V(f(\mathfrak{m}_e))$ is the closed subscheme of $H$ defined by the ideal $I:=f(\mathfrak{m}_e)$. Hence if $k[H]$ is finite dimensional over $k$ it follows $k[K]:=k[H]/I$ is finite dimensional over $k$.